# Wordpress inserting comments via wp_insert_comment()

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, function

Hello all happy holidays! :)

I'm trying to insert comments in my wordpress blog via the `wp_insert_comment()` function. It's for a plugin I'm trying to make.

I have this code in my header for testing. It works every time I refresh the page.

```
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$data = array(
    'comment_post_ID' => 256,
    'comment_author' => 'Dave',
    'comment_author_email' => 'dave@domain.com',
    'comment_author_url' => 'http://www.someiste.com',
    'comment_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
    'comment_author_IP' => '127.3.1.1',
    'comment_agent' => $agent,
    'comment_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'comment_date_gmt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'comment_approved' => 1,
);

$comment_id = wp_insert_comment($data);
```

It successfully inserts comments into the database.

The problem: Comments don't show via the [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) comment system. I compared table rows and I noticed that user_agent differs.

Normal comments use for example, `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv...`

and Disqus comments use `Disqus/1.1(2.61):119598902`  numbers are different for each comment.

Does anyone know how to insert comments with `wp_insert_comment()` when Disqus is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Disqus imports comments from the WordPress database in real-time.  If you wanted it to appear in Disqus' database immediately, you'd need to insert it via [the Disqus API](http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/create/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this parameters:

```
'comment_type' => '',
```

Try to use this code:

```
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$data = array(
    'comment_post_ID' => 256,
    'comment_author' => 'Dave',
    'comment_author_email' => 'dave@domain.com',
    'comment_author_url' => 'http://www.someiste.com',
    'comment_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
    'comment_author_IP' => '127.3.1.1',
    'comment_agent' => $agent,
    'comment_type'  => '',
    'comment_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'comment_date_gmt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'comment_approved' => 1,
```

);

```
$comment_id = wp_insert_comment($data);
```